# How to convert this Jquery code to React JS?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have used this Jquery code in a .jsx file within the ComponentDidMount(){}.

But I want to write this in ReactJS. How should I do this?

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".owl-item", function() {
      // $(this).css('border','5px solid red')
      $(this)
        .prevAll(".active")
        .addClass("hover-prev");
      $(this)
        .nextAll(".active")
        .addClass("hover-next");
    });
$(document).on("mouseout", ".owl-item", function() {
      $(this)
        .prevAll(".active")
        .removeClass("hover-prev");
      $(this)
        .nextAll(".active")
        .removeClass("hover-next");
    });
```

html of the code (used react owl carousel...".owl-item" is predefined within the carousel itself)

```
<OwlCarousel ref="car" options={options}>
            <div>
              <img src={Actor} class="circleBase" alt="Cinque Terre" />
              <div className="h6 text-center mt-2">Cast Name</div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <img src={Actor} class=" circleBase " alt="Cinque Terre" />
              <div className=" h6 text-center mt-2">Cast Name</div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <img src={Actor} class=" circleBase" alt="Cinque Terre" />
              <div className="h6 text-center mt-2">Cast Name</div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <img src={Actor} class=" circleBase" alt="Cinque Terre" />
              <div className="h6 text-center mt-2">Cast Name</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={Actor} class=" circleBase" alt="Cinque Terre" />
              <div className="h6 text-center mt-2">Cast Name</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={Actor} class=" circleBase" alt="Cinque Terre" />
              <div className="h6 text-center mt-2">Cast Name</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={Actor} class=" circleBase" alt="Cinque Terre" />
              <div className="h6 text-center mt-2">Cast Name</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={Actor} class=" circleBase type" alt="Cinque Terre" />
              <div className="h6 text-center mt-2">Cast Name</div>
            </div>
          </OwlCarousel>
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Comment: You could change a state variable on mouse enter / mouse out (see events that @mplungjan referenced), and depending on what the state variable is set to, set class `hover-next` or `hover-prev`. If you show the HTML of your element `.owl-item` we can help further